# If there are slots consisting of n numbers, which will x fit into?

Tags: python, numbers, grouping

This is a little bit hard to phrase... Basically, my question is as follows. If all the numbers up to z are divided into groups of n, which will x fit into. For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
|_______| |_______|  |___________|

    0         1            2
```

so in this example, n = 5, there are groups of five. z = 15. Let's say x = 9. How can I write a function that will return 1 for x = 9 because its in the group with the index position of 1, and that will return 2 for x = 12? I'm having trouble researching this, because I'm having a hard time explaining it. I get the feeling it's deceptively simple... I'm using python 2.7. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I hope this question follows the guidelines for good questions, I seem to be having trouble with that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide `x` by `n`. The only hitch is that you need to subtract `1` first, because your sequence starts at `1` rather than `0`.

```
def whichSlot(x, n):
    return (x - 1) // n
```

Answer (score 1):

If `n` are all the same size, it's simple integer division

```
(x-1)//5
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something obvious!